# Crontab issues with python script

Tags: python, import, cron, anaconda, pythonpath

I have a script that runs perfectly from command line:

```
/home/anaconda2/bin/python /project_folder/script.py
```

I added some details below:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/project_folder/

$ which python
/home/anaconda2/bin/python
```

Which runs the script perfectly, flawlessly.

Then from within crontab (which has been successful for another script that didn't have local import issues) I can't get the script to run.

Crontab of code that doesn't work:

```
PYTHONPATH=/project_folder
* * * * * /home/anaconda2/bin/python /project_folder/script.py
```

Nothing happens.  It's killing me and much of my time trying to figure this one out - any help much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure any environment variables your script needs are defined. Cron doesn't run all the same start up scripts an interactive login runs.

Comment: There are some useful tips here for crons that silently fail: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged

Comment: How would I go about figuring that out @GreenMatt (thanks btw)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to figure out: That cron doesn't run all the start up scripts your interactive login does? That comes from reading the docs, which usually comes from trying to figure out why your script does not run from cron! ;-) What environment variables are needed? Trial and error or examining your start up scripts are how I usually figure it out. Also, cron may be emailing results or logging them. I would suggest looking at your .bashrc (or equivalent) to see if you're making changes to your PATH or PYTHONPATH variables as a starting point.

Comment: I noticed this line (at end of comment) in my bashrc which was the only env variable I saw - however I am not sure how to include that into crontab   >>> export PATH="/var/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"

Comment: @SteelyDanish: One approach is to have cron call a Bash wrapper script which sets up the PATH and then runs your Python script. Alternatively, there are ways to set up the environment from with a Python script; have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python

Comment: @GreenMatt - thanks did that it worked.  Posting answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it via creating a wrapper shell script. Ugly in that i'm exporting the python path each time, but it works.

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/project_folder"
source ~/.bash_profile
cd /project_folder && /my/anaconda/location/bin/python /project_folder/cript.py
```